# How to add a page break or newpage in proof environment

Tags: page-breaking, proof-package, aligned

[image]

My code is very unclear, but to summarise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Section}

\begin{proof}
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
Text\\
\text{Equations}\\
\text{How to add a page break inside aligned, and proof environment??}\\
\end{aligned}
$

\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

So any ways to add a pagebreak or newpage???

Comment: you can not page break in aligned, it's an inline box like `\fbox`   use `\begin{align*}` not `$\begin{aligned}`

Comment: Even with `align`, if a page break is wanted in the middle, '\allowbreaks` must be active.  (Documentation in the `amsmath` user guide.)